# Example for clickable TableRow in Android

Tags: android, row, tablelayout, clickable

I have a table of texts with each row having a text. I want to display a popup when one of the rows in the table is clicked. Does TableLayout in android support this? If so, is there an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the onClickListener with the TextView in each row. Or you could set it directly on TableRow directly

```
android.widget.TableRow tableRow = ..
tableRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick() {
    }
});
```

[OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Programatically doing it i used this code inside onCreate method of my activity:

```
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //codigoo
                }
            });
```

I had to use the `View.OnClickListener` and the `@Override` or it wouldnt work!